# White Error Screen Appears when I try to add from form

Tags: python, django-forms

I am getting a white error screen when I try to add an item via a form in python / django. I am trying to debug it but there is no information. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had the size max length in the needs field. I originally had 1 instead of 3 in my forms.py file.

```html
class KidDetailsForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=None, required=False)
    dob = forms.CharField(max_length=10, required=False)
    gender = forms.CharField(max_length=1, required=False)
    needs = forms.CharField(max_length=3, required=False)
```